# Why i cant rename a file?

Tags: c#, sftp

I am trying to rename a file after i upload it with an .tmp extension.

I want to change te file extention to .xml .

Im using Renci in C# to able to connect to my SFTP server.

In my catch exception this is the error message ""Failed to rename file".

```
    using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(infoConnection))
    {
      client.Connect();
      if (client.IsConnected)
      {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(content))
         {   client.Create(path + filenametemp);
             client.WriteAllText(path + filenametemp, XML);
             client.BufferSize = (uint)ms.Length;
             client.UploadFile(ms, path + attachment);
             client.RenameFile(path + filenametemp, path + filename);
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Did you code the Exception to return that message or is that the actual Exception? Why don't you name the file before uploading?

Comment: This is the actual exception. In your opinion where should i rename the file?

Comment: I don't know that library but it looks like `filenametemp` is an opportunity to name the file before uploading.

Comment: Is it possible that a file with the name `filename` already exists? Is there no inner exception or something giving more information?

Comment: Sorry guys . I know where was my mistake. My filenametemp should be like "123.xml.tmp" and it was 123.tmp"

Comment: Moreover you actually have two uploads there (`client.WriteAllText` and `client.UploadFile`) --- and you didn't explain their meaning/relation to the question (if it's even deliberate and not a bug).

Answer (score 2):

You are uploading the file using one name (path + attachment), but then you try to rename the uploaded file using a different name (path + filenametemp). Try this instead:

```
         client.UploadFile(ms, path + filenametemp);
         client.RenameFile(path + filenametemp, path + filename);
```

Comment: Look carefully to the code. I am creating a file with filenametemp that attcahment is another file. But thanks for the awnser. I know where i have done my mistake.